# Can a MemberExpression return a Method

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, func

I would like to return a method (or method info) with some sort of Lambda expression in C#.

```
public class MyClass {
    public object ReturnSomething(string arg, int numericArg)
    {/*...*/}
}
```

Then, later, I would like to reference this method using a Lambda like so..

```
public static void Run<T>(T sourceObject, Expression<Func<T, object>> memberExpression, IEnumerable<object> parameters)
{
    var methodInfo = ((MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body).Member as MethodInfo;
    if (methodInfo == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("memberExpression must yield a method");
    /*...*/
}
```

I've tried using this with something like:

```
var myClassObject = new MyClass();
Run(myClassObject, o => o.ReturnSomething, new object["string arg", 1]);
```

But I keep getting this compiler error on my expression:

> Cannot convert method group 'ReturnSomething' to non-delegate type
>   'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Is this doable in c# or should I give up and pass a string with the method name and use reflection for the look up instead of using a MemberExpression?

Comment: can't say i understand the point of it, why would you need to do this?  the whole point of dynamic execution is to allow a non coded source to drive execution, this approach requires you provide the method and arguments.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

T McKeown asks the right question above, I was half-way using dynamic execution when it was easy enough to provide the arguments in my lambda expression.

I resolved this by not doing dumb-stuff.. Instead of returning the actual method, I changed the structure to us an expression that performs the execution in-line. Seems much cleaner than where I was originally going.

The intent was to compare the execution of two similarly classed objects to make sure they both return the same values. This is done because I am in the middle of a rewrite and wish to make sure my new methods return the same as my old methods.

Here's where I ended up with:

```
public static void CompareExecutions<TObject, TParameter, TReturn>(this TObject originalSource, TObject alternateSource, IEnumerable<TParameter> parameters, Func<TObject, TParameter, TReturn> testExpression)
    where TObject : class
    where TReturn : class
{
    var originalResults = new List<TReturn>();
    using (new Profile("Original Source"))
        foreach (var parameterSet in parameters)
            originalResults.Add(testExpression(originalSource, parameterSet));

    var alternateResults = new List<TReturn>();
    using (new Profile("Alternate Source"))
        foreach (var parameterSet in parameters)
            alternateResults.Add(testExpression(alternateSource, parameterSet));

    var comparer = new PropertyComparer<TReturn>();
    int errorCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(originalResults[i], alternateResults[i]))
        {
            errorCount++;
            Debug.WriteLine("^--- Mismatch for parameter {0}:\r\n\t{1}", i, string.Join("\r\n\t", parameters.ElementAt(i)));
        }
    }

    if (errorCount > 0)
        Assert.Fail("The results did not match for {0} items", errorCount);
}
```

I use it like this:

```
public class OriginalClass
{
    public virtual ResultClass MyMethod(string argOne, int argTwo)
    {/*...*/}
}

public class DerivedClass: OriginalClass
{
    public override ResultClass MyMethod(string argOne, int argTwo)
    {/*New implementation of the original code...*/}
}
//[...]
public void TestTheseTwoClasses() {
    var original = new OriginalClass();
    var derivedClass = new DerivedClass();

    original.CompareExecutions(
        derivedClass,
        new[] {
            new {One = "First", Two=1},
            new {One = "Second", Two=2},
            new {One = "Third", Two=3}
        },
        (c,p) => c.MyMethod(p.One, p.Two)
    );
}
```